# How to add more random questions to this logo quiz?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I created a logo quiz app this week but the problem with this logo quiz is that it only has one question. After answering, the quiz ends.
I would like to know how to add more questions to this quiz and how to show the questions randomly. 
I mean after answering the question, another random picture appears. I am kinda new in android development and I still require assistance from other developers and I believe this is the best place to ask.
 Thank you very much in advance for helping me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int presCounter = 0;
private int maxPresCounter = 5;
private String[] keys = {"S", "A", "M", "P", "L"};
private String textAnswer = "SAMPL";
TextView textScreen, textQuestion, textTitle;
@Override
protected void onCreate....
    keys = shuffleArray(keys);
    for (String key : keys) {
        addView(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutParent)), key, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)));
    }
    maxPresCounter = 5;
}


private String[] shuffleArray(String[] ar) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        String a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
    return ar;
}


private void addView(LinearLayout viewParent, final String text, final EditText editText) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    linearLayoutParams.rightMargin = 30;

    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    textView.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
    textView.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pix));

    textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);
    textScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScreen);
    textTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(presCounter < maxPresCounter) {
                if (presCounter == 0)
                    editText.setText("");
                    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + text);
                    presCounter++;
                    if (presCounter == maxPresCounter)
                        doValidate();
            }
        }
    });

    viewParent.addView(textView);
}
private void doValidate() {
    presCounter = 0;
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutParent);
    if(editText.getText().toString().equals(textAnswer)) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        editText.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editText.setText("");
    }
    keys = shuffleArray(keys);
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (String key : keys) {
        addView(linearLayout, key, editText);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to have random questions, then your app should have more than 1 question. Keep an array of questions and post random questions. check the result after the question has been answered and based on the result, you can either generate next random question or terminate application.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance